# How to declare webContents to TypeScript in Electron 15

Tags: typescript, electron

### Description

Upgrading to Electron 14 → 15 introduces the following TypeScript build error for my main process.

> error TS2749: 'webContents' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof webContents'?

The delcarations in the code are

```js
import { webContents, dialog } from 'electron';

// ...

logContents: webContents | undefined
```

The build gave me no problem with Electron 14 and before.

### Reproduction

The problem is simple to reproduce.

1. Clone repo.

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/pglezen/electron-typescript-svelte-starter e15
   ```
2. Install dependencies.

   ```
   cd e15
   npm install
   npm ls electron
   ```

   This should verify Electron 14 installation.
3. Run main process build.

   ```
   npm run build:main
   ```

   No errors should be encountered.
4. Upgrade to Electron 15.

   ```
   npm install electron@15.1.0
   ```
5. Rerun build.

   ```
   npm run build:main
   ```

The full error text is listed below.

```
src/main/Logger.ts:13:16 - error TS2749: 'webContents' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof webContents'?

13   logContents: webContents | undefined;
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~

src/main/Logger.ts:14:17 - error TS2749: 'webContents' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof webContents'?

14   mainContents: webContents | undefined;
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 2 errors.
```

### Attempted Fixes

#### 1. Import `webContents` as a type.

I changed the `webContents` declaration to

```
import type { webContents } from 'electron';
```

**Result**: No change in the message.

#### 2. Use the TypeScript `typeof` operator

This was suggested in the error message.

**Result**: Removed the above error message; but introduced the following error where I tried to invoke a function call on `webContents`:

> TS2339: Property 'send' does not exist on type 'typeof WebContents'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this API underwent some changes in the latest version. But at least as of version 15, you aren't using this API correctly.

[According to the docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents) the value you get from the `webContents` module, has [these methods](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#methods).

And the instances of `WebContents` that come from `BrowserWindow`s have [these methods](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#class-webcontents)

These are completely different values and types.

[Playground here that illustrates the difference.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgdwKYCMDCEB2NV4DOANHAOobZ4EwlwBCUEyhqUZwOAJs3AL5wAZkxBwA5KgA2qAMYwmOMQG4AsACh1aLLnxEAdAHNUMAIKTJFbdSIAKAJRwA9I7gHJEdAENJcEMYAWEFyEcJ7oEACu8N4+yJw8LCjQANZw-myoepqUOjSEeqzc9k4uAGImAJIAMnpwMP7AIX7+MEFwPKghOBDwqAAejfDpUJnq6jK4hPBx3MyWVLq0AFzkOda0cAC8cDioyAxMLGwcs8j2eloLeZrxc2uL+YVcNmL4U5wGYg7O5ADyAEoAaQAymM1EA)

---

You probably want the `webContents` that comes from `BrowserWindow`. In which those appear to be instances of the `WebContents` (note the capital `W`) class which you can import and use as you expect.

```
import { WebContents, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';

const windowWebContents: WebContents = new BrowserWindow().webContents
windowWebContents.send('testing') // WORKS
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex, for straightening me out.  Using WebContents instead of webContents resolved my build issues.